# Who is using their Persona for their career and how?

Tags: persona

in *Shin Megami Tensei Persona 2: Eternal Punishment* in Kei Nanjo;s route, when you talk to him in the Velvet Room he talks about how he used to use it quite often.

He also says that Persona are useful for not only fighting saying that a friend of his, who has become a salesman, is using his Persona to succeed in his career commenting that if only Reiji Kido was that clever.

I assume since Reiji and Kei are both Persona Users from *Shin Megami Tensei Persona* i assume it's either the slient nameable protagonist or Masao Inaba but not sure who. i am wondering who Kei is referring to and just how they are using their Persona to succeed in their career?